# Selecting the clicked element and not its parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a bunch of nested lists:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3
        <ul>
            <li>child-1</li>
            <li>child-2
                <ul>
                    <li>grand-child 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With jQuery, with a click or hover, I want to use the item (li). But it gives me it's parent. 
As in: If I click (or hover) grand-child 1, $(this) returns ITEM-3 (parent's parent)

My jQuery code:

```
$('ul li').live('click', function(e) {
    someVar = $(this).data("dataname"); // (can be .attr(""), etc.);
});
```

When any of the Li is clicked, how can I use that particular one and not the parent in which it's nested?

Comment: not clear what issue is...  clcik or hover, you always get "this" as element, traverse from $(this) to do what is needed

Comment: The issue, as I stated in the question itself, is that, $(this) gives me the Up-Most parent LI not the LI which is clicked.

Comment: no it doesn't , create a fiddle.net demo

Comment: No, you are right. It doesn't and I just have fun here stating a non-existing imaginary issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this help. if you see console.log, it only return the current clicked item. Read the documentation on stopPropagation [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

> "The docs states that stopPropagation Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event."

I also updated live to on, as live has been deprecated as of 1.7

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log($(this)); 
});
```

Comment: I love you! Thank you so much! I swear I was going nuts as I searched and searched but couldn't come up with this. THANK YOU, really! THANK YOU! ;-) Ps. I was about to use delegate but on seems better. Thank you again and again and, again!!

Answer (score 2):

I think below is what you are looking for,

```
$('ul li').live('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    someVar = $(this).data("dataname"); 
});
```

`e.stopPropagation();` stop any event propagated to other matching `ul li`

**Note:** Please use `.on` if you are using `jQuery v1.7` as `.live` is deprecated.

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).text()); // (can be .attr(""), etc.);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/cHSmm/)